# setTimeout() or delay() not working in js function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add delay or setTimeout after the startSound() but could not able to add. If I add, it not working. I want a delay of 5-10sec after the sound is complete. 
And also want to add an html code like "YOU WIN $2000" after `startSound()`.

JS CODE:

```
self.rightAnswer = function(elm) {

    $("#" + elm).fadeOut(1500, function() {
        if (self.level() == 5 || self.level() == 10) {

        startSound('wrongsound2', false);

        $("#" + elm).css('background', 'url(boxright.png) no-repeat 0 0').fadeIn(800, function() {
                self.money($(".active").data('amt'));
                if(self.level() + 1 > 15) {
                    $("#game").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $("#game-over").html('You Win!');
                        $("#game-over").fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                } else {
                    self.level(self.level() + 1);
                    $("#" + elm).css('background','url(box.png) no-repeat 0 0');
                    $("#" + elm).hover(function(){
                        $(this).css("background", "url(boxhover.png) no-repeat 0 0");
                    }, function(){
                        $(this).css('background','url(box.png) no-repeat 0 0');
                        });
                    $("#answer-one").show();
                    $("#answer-two").show();
                    $("#answer-three").show();
                    $("#answer-four").show();
                    self.transitioning = false;
                }
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did not write *how* you tried to use that function. The stardard is something like that:

```
self.rightAnswer = function(elm) {

    $("#" + elm).fadeOut(1500, function() {
        if (self.level() == 5 || self.level() == 10) {

            startSound('wrongsound2', false);
            setTimeout(function(){
                // whatever commands you want to get executed after 5 seconds go here...
            }, 5000);
            [...]
```

So basically you hand over some function to the `setTimeout()` call (an anonymous function here) and the desired time to delay in milli seconds. That's all.

*Note:* javascript (mostly) follows an asynchronous approach. The script execution is *not* delayed for that amount of time. So any commands after the call to the `setTimeout()` function are executed immediately. Only those commands handed over in said function are delayed because that function is called then. Think of it like pushing commands into a queue which will get triggered after the specified amount of time. `setTimeout()` is *not* a pause/sleep function. It only registers jobs into the delay queue and returns immediately.

Comment: Not working Bro....when I click on correct option, it fadeout and sound complete and then stop evrything...

Comment: OK, that does not mean that the `setTimeout()`call itself is not working. Probably something is wrong with the code you placed inside that function you hand over. I suggest you start by checking for javascript errors in your browsers development console, then by debugging your script in there or you post the actual code you try.

Comment: so how can I add delay of 5-10 sec? if it not work in this way as u did.

Comment: I get this error on Console Debug: "ReferenceError: SetTimeout is not defined"

Comment: `SetTimeout` is something else than `setTimeout`. The code is case sensitive.

Comment: Oh, ooops, sorry, just saw that I made that mistake myself in my code snippet above. Sorry for that, fixed it. It has to be `setTimeout()`, obviously.

Comment: Yup...Done it...now how can I add Html code after the sound is end??? mean I want to show ("You have won" self.money()).

Comment: That is a separate question, isn't it? It also depends on what (if any) javascript libraries you use and _how_ you want to display that string.

Comment: Yes. I want to show it using HTML DOM. document.getElementById. But if I add this, it shows you win 300 and it not fade out for new question. Means, it keep on right answer.

Comment: As said: that is a separate question. Please open a new question for that. And add the exact code you try which fails, tell exactly what errors you see in the javascript console or any other details that may be relevant. Keep in mind that we cannot see over your shoulder...